# How to sort searched files in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When we are searching using ctrl + shift + f command in visual studio code for entire project , we are getting multiple files listing in which search values found.

Is there any way so that I can sort those search files because visual studio code not showing sorted search files.

I have gone through official website but not able to find such command.

[image: Sort_html_files]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803444/sort-order-of-result-for-find-all-references-in-visual-studio

Possible Duplicate for your reference

Comment: Thanks but have checked above post but still not able to find any answer from above post.

Comment: The files are sorted by **relative-path**, sorting them by fileBasename would be really weird.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked to find similiar option to sort files as you are asking in visual studio code but not able to find any but you can see that visual code already sorting those file based on folder like account,base etc...

You can try regex to search to minify your serach criteria like a*.html, bo*.html, 
[abc]*.html.

Hope above help you to sort out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can (now?) sort results by updating user settings. **Settings > Search "sort order"**. You'll see a few options:

- Search: Sort Order - Sorting search results
- Explorer: Sort Order - Sorting files in the file explorer